# Random integers in R

Tags: r, integer

What code in R will do the following:

Given a list 1, 2, ..., M create a list of N random entries from that list. Furthermore, obtain the complement list.

```
example:
N = 5
M = 10
list = [1,4,3,9,2]
complement = [5,6,7,8,10]
```

Comment: It's actually "complement", if you care.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?sample`

```
samp_range <- 1:M
out <- sample(samp_range, N)
compliment <- samp_range[!samp_range %in% out]
```

or as per Joran's comment:

```
compliment <- setdiff(samp_range, out)
```

Also, as a rule, avoid using things like `list` as variable names since they are internal R functions.

Comment: Nice. I'll add a note about `setdiff` in a comment here and delete mine.

Comment: or just out <- sample(M,N); compliment <- samp_range[-out]